# find path in binary unsorted tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I need help finding the path from the root to a node in a binary unsorted tree. I am trying with pre-order traversal and pushing the nodes in the stack but i always get more nodes than the actual path.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation error, so could you maybe post some code?

Comment: Do you mean find the 'shortest' path?  Maybe edit your title.

Comment: A tree does not "push" nodes into a "stack"; it inserts them.  It does  seem to be implementation rather than design; could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

A good way for doing this is to keap in each node a parent's references, then if you can access to the node build the path is easy, only you need go throught all parents and build the path. If you have not access to the node and the only that you have is the tree root, then you need to search in all possibles subtrees, that is because the tree is unsorted. Then you may use pre-order, post-order, in-order for a DFS (Deep First Search) or implement some BFS (Breadth First Search) using a queue.

Hope this may helps you...

Comment: My idea was to find the path from the root to the root using one of the dfs searches. But everytime I use one of the traversals if the node is in the right subtree of the root the path first find the ones in the left subtree of the root than on the right, so the path comes out wrong. By the way I only have access to the root.